# How to get the proper Javascript output for the number pyramid

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am currently working on a 1/2 pyramid of numbers. I can get the output to total up the line and get everything but the * sign between the numbers. Hoping that someone out there can lend a helping hand. Here is the code that I have completed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Assignment 1</title>
    <script>
        var num = "";
        var match ="";


var size = prompt("Enter the size of the pyramid");
if (size >=1) {
var total="1";

for(var i=1; i<=size; i++)
{
    if (i < size){
  num = num  +  i + " " 

  } if (i==size) {
  num =num + i }


   total= total * i;
  document.write(num   + " = "+ total + "<br>"); 
}
 }else {
 alert("Please enter a number equal to or greater than 1");
 }
var total="1";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <!-- Will show after the script has run -->
        <h1>Assignment 1</h1>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

-

I am looking for output like this

```
1=1
1*2=2
1*2*3=6
1*2*3*4=24
1*2*3*4*5=120
```

and so on.
Thanks again

Comment: prompt returns a string or null. you should be converting the result to a number first.

Comment: So what is wrong with what you got? Why is there `var total="1";` after the loop? I do not see you adding a `*` when you are building your string.

Comment: Please use proper (and consistent) indentation. This will make your (and our) life easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop like this and make the total time the new iteration value:

```js
var total = 1;
var newList = [];
for(let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  newList.push(i);
  total *= i;
  console.log(newList.join('*') + '=' + total)
}
```

Run code snippet output:

```
1=1
1*2=2
1*2*3=6
1*2*3*4=24
1*2*3*4*5=120
```